# mysql partitioning by day

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration, partitioning

Hello i want to add partitioning to my table.
the table multimedia contanins record from the last 7 days
so i want to create 7 partition, one partition - one day
so a try to execute this migration:

```
def up
execute "ALTER TABLE multimedia 
  partition by range (to_days(created_at))
  ( 
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (6 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (5 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (4 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(#{Time.now - (0 * 24 * 60 * 60)})),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
  );"
end
```

the result of the migration is the followe error:

```
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'11:09:43 +0200)),
     PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-18 11:0' at line 4: ALTER TABLE  multimedia                        
    partition by range (to_days(created_at))
    ( 

  ==  AddPartitionToMultimedia: migrating =======================================
 -- 
  execute("ALTER TABLE multimedia \n      
partition by range (to_days(created_at))\n      
( \n        
PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-17 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-18 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-19 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-20 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-21 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-22 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-23 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-24 11:09:43 +0200)),\n        
PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE \n      
);")
```

Comment: the error is:

An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near:

Comment: '11:09:43 +0200)), PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days(2012-04-18 11:0' at line 4: ALTER TABLE multimedia
partition by range (to_days(created_at)) ('

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There error is in you `to_days` function. You need to make sure that the value passed to your `to_days` is of type of string. Something like the code below:

```
to_days('2012-04-17 11:09:43 +0200')
        ^                         ^
        |                         |
```